# How do you change the URL of an existing XMLHttpRequest object (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

After setting and sending an XMLHttpRequest, I want to be able to change the URL of the XMLHttpRequest, resend it, and change the existing content.

In my example, I want a user to be able to type in keywords into an input tag, press a "Search" button, and the XMLHttpRequest will be updated with what they typed in the input tag. The request opens to a PHP script that CURLs data from a news website and takes the keywords and format type (rss or json) in its query string.

I've seen references to beforeSend() in other threads, but I have no knowledge of jQuery and was hoping to do it without it.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
        .
        .
        .
        function search() { 
            // search() is a function that is called by a <input="button"> above
            // keywords is a <input type="text"> in the rest of the HTML document above
            keywords = "q=" + document.getElementById("keywords").value;
            getRequest();
            return false;
        }

        function getRequest() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", address + "?" + format + keywords, true);
            alert(address + "?" + format + "&" + keywords);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                switch (request.readyState) {
                    case 4:
                        //retrieved_articles is a <div> in the rest of the HTML above
                        document.getElementById("retrieved_articles").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            request.send();
        }
```

Comment: Where are `address` and `format` defined?

Comment: put your ajax request into something like $("#input_field_id").change(function(){
      search();
});
inside document ready function or something equivalent in javascript.